# Date literals in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Today I accidentally forgot to added the quote marks around date literals, like this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dayofyear, '2017-02-05'),  -- with quote marks 
       DATENAME(dayofyear, 2017-02-05)     -- without quote marks
```

Surprisingly, instead of signalling a `TypeError` or something similiar, this query returned a "success" message with two columns:

```
701 91
```

It is obvious that `91` means 2017-02-05 is the 91st day of 2017. However, the `701` does not make sense, for one year can have at most 366 days.

My question is: how does SQL Server interpret date literals? And how invalid date literals like `2017-02-05` are handled? SQL Server is presumably following the practice of *garbage in, bargage out*, which I can understand, but I hate "slient" errors like this, so I'd like to know what's happening behind the scenes, so that spotting such errors might be easier.

Comment: when i run it sql server 2012 i got 36 and 185 in result

Comment: Unquoted is just a mathematical expression, consisting of a number and two subtractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run

```
SELECT CAST(2017-02-05 AS DATETIME)
```

It would return
`1905-07-04 00:00`

What seemed to happen was that 2010(Difference of 2017-2-5) was treated as the number of days after 1900-01-01 (base sql date)

so 1900-01-01 + 2010 days = jul 4 1905

When I ran your query however, what I got was
`36` and `185` since jul 4 is the 185th day of the year 1905.